# Why no-liquibase enabled for production?

Tags: heroku, jhipster, liquibase

Why is the `no-liquibase` profile enabled for production ? I thought that we need liquibase to run in order to run all the migrates at the start of the app ?

Comment: Do you mean e.g. when using the heroku subgen and maven?

Comment: @atomfrede yes, I am using heroku subgen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the heroku sub gen with maven the application starts with `no-liquibase` as the liquibase migration is done via the [release phase in heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase). Your generated [procfile contains a dedicated release phase](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/0b1b36e6d4c1ac50af278ad2e873f5b88a02b475/generators/heroku/templates/Procfile.ejs#L21) which does `liquibase:update` such that the database migration is done before starting the application. This is in particular helpful if you have a lot of entities for example and use the free dynos as on free dynos your app needs to start in 90s.